# How to check if a node's value in a xml file is always taken from another fix node's value using xsl/xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am checking some conditions in xml file using xsl/xslt 1.0 version. For one of the checks I have to make sure that a node's value can only be taken from another node's value. For example:

sample.xml:

```
<fruit-garden>
    <fruit-available>
        <fruit>apple</fruit>
        <fruit>banana</fruit>
    </fruit-available>
    <fruit-for-dinner>
        <fruit>apple</fruit>[should-be-fine]
        <fruit>mango</fruit>[should-not-be-fine]
    </fruit-for-dinner>
</fruit-garden>
```

Here in sample.xml, suppose we need `/fruit-for-dinner/fruit` value to be only from one of the values of `/fruit-available/fruit` As of XSLT 1.0, I'm not able to think of a method to program this.

I thought maybe [set:difference](http://exslt.org/set/functions/difference/index.html) can be useful here but looks like it operates on a fix node-path. Any hint in the right direction will be helpful for me.

Comment: You cannot use `set:difference()` because `fruit-available/fruit` and `fruit-for-dinner/fruit` are two different node-sets to begin with. You need to compare the **values**, either directly or - preferably - using a **key** as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<xsl:key name="available-fruits" match="fruit-available/fruit" use="."/>` and then you can check e.g. `<xsl:template match="fruit-for-dinner/fruit[not(key('available-fruits', .)]">not right</xsl:template>`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question you can use any variation of these two templates to eat or not.  Create a key match, then use it.  I made this slightly verbose to show two uses of it (match or not)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:key name="available" match="fruit-available/fruit" use="." /> 
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <garden>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="fruit-garden"/>
        </garden>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/fruit-garden">
        <caneat>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="fruit-for-dinner/fruit[key('available', .)]"/>
        </caneat>
        <bob-ate-it>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="fruit-for-dinner/fruit[not(key('available', .))]"/>
        </bob-ate-it>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="fruit"> 
        <eatme>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </eatme>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sample output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<garden>
   <caneat>
      <eatme>apple</eatme>
      <eatme>pear</eatme>
   </caneat>
   <bob-ate-it>
      <eatme>mango</eatme>
   </bob-ate-it>
</garden>
```